# How to nest views with bindings?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, prism

I am using Xamarin.Forms with Prism.

Given a Place Model with Properties as Street, City etc. and a Route View which allows the user to define two Places, Starting Place and Target Place, I want to define a Place View to include in the Route View to avoid repeating code.

The resulting RouteView may be like

```
<label Text="Starting Place" />
<controls:PlaceView
   Place="{Binding StartingPlace}" />
<label Text="Target Place" />
<controls:PlaceView
   Place="{Binding TargetPlace}" />
```

Where Place is a Bindable Property in PlaceView and StartingPlace and TargetPlace are instances of the Place Model in the Routes View Model.

I have tried realizing the Bindings in the PlaceView via

```
<Label Text="Street" />
<Entry Text="{Binding Place.Street}" />
```

but that is not working. Changes in the UI do not result in changes of the Place instance.

So what would be the most elegant way to bind the Place's Properties to the nested view? I want to avoid to explicit name all of them in each instantiation.

I have two ideas in mind, how this eventually could be realized, but I am not sure how to implement them.

1. Create a View Model for PlaceView and create Properties there which would connect for example Street to Place.Street. Is this possible and when yes then how to get access to the given Place from inside the View Model?
2. Implement this connections inside the Place View's code. Here I am not sure how to do this.

**Edited:**

To clearify, model is like following

```
class Place
{
    private string _street;
    public string Street
    {
        get => _street;
        set => _street = value;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

This like is the current view model (RouteViewViewModel)

```
public class RouteViewViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private Place _startingPlace;
    public Place StartingPlace
    {
        get => _startingPlace;
        set => SetProperty(ref _startingPlace, value);
    }
    // TargetPlace is equivalent
}
```

[Current Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gHE2.png)

## Solution

Thanks to @Sharada Gururaj I came to a result, which is [available on Github](https://github.com/micdahl/NestedBinding).

Comment: have you set SetPropertyChanged(nameof(StartingPlace)); and SetPropertyChanged(nameof(TargetPlace)); in model?

Comment: @PavanVParekh How do you mean that? The model (Place) does not know about the context it is used in, so there are neither TargetPlace nor StartingPlace in the model.
It's just a plain class containing Properties like Street and City (see edited question).

Comment: Your (view-)model needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` anyway. If you create `Bindings` to the properties of classes that don't implement this interface, you won't be able to update the UI and (depending on the .NET Framework version) you might get a memory leak.

Comment: Ok, it seems there is some confusion between the Model (Place), which is a simple C# Class, and the ViewModel (RouteViewViewModel). The RouteViewViewModel does implement BindableBase and has Properties for StartingPlace and TargetPlace. For the nested PlaceView there is no ViewModel at the moment. My question is about if implementing one would be possible and helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Create a View Model for PlaceView and create Properties there which would connect for example Street to Place.Street. Is this possible and when yes then how to get access to the given Place from inside the View Model?

The answer is yes, it would be helpful to have a view-model for `PlaceView` - or atleast ensure that `Place` implements property change notification i.e. `INotifyPropertyChanged`

> 2. Implement this connections inside the Place View's code. Here I am not sure how to do this.

Once point 1 is complete - **either simply change your binding** to use parent control as `Source` (and, add named reference inside `PlaceView` XAML):

```
<ContentView x:Class="AppNamespace.PlaceView" x:Name="_parent">
        <Label Text="Street" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding Path=Place.Street, Source={x:Reference _parent}}" />
```

**Or use `BindingContext`,**

```
<!-- PlaceView usage --> 
<controls:PlaceView BindingContext="{Binding StartingPlace}" />

<!-- Update binding in PlaceView control XAML -->
<Label Text="Street" />
<Entry Text="{Binding Path=Street}" />
```

Comment: So if I create a View Model for PlaceView `PlaceViewViewModel : Bindable Base`, how do I get access to the bound Place inside of the ViewModels' class? I.e. how to `public string Street { set => _place.street = value; }`? Where do I get the `_place`, which has to be the bound Place from the RouteView (i.e. StartingPlace/TargetPlace), from inside of the View Model?

Comment: I am exactly sure if I understood your question - so please bear with me here.

Comment: If you are creating a viewmodel for PlaceView - then your `public Place StartingPlace` becomes `public PlaceViewModel StartingPlace` and so-on for other properties in RouteViewModel; and you will need to translate your model to view model. For example: you can do that in constructor of viewmodel `public PlaceViewModel(Place place) { this.Street = place.Street; ... }`

Comment: Did it through your help! Many Thanks!
For everybody else who gets into this issue, I created a [GitHub repository which contains the running result](https://github.com/micdahl/NestedBinding)